# How to delete part of a string in SQLite based on detecting a newline character?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need help with constructing an SQL query that will give the following result:

I have a table `group_message`

> For all rows where the column `parent_id` fields are different than `0`
>
> affect every respective field in the column `content`
>
> by deleting all text occurring before the first newline character that you will find, and preserve the remaining text (that might contain other newline characters).

(Most of my `content` fields contain an unwanted header-like element in the first line of the text that I'd like to get rid of, and in all cases there is a newline character occuring after the part I want to be gone).

- `parent_id` is INTEGER
- `content` is BLOB, but all fields are actually text only
- There is a general `id` column that can help with `WHERE` statements
- SQLite 3.27.1

I have 19.7k rows in that table from which 16.4k should be affected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update by assigning to `content` the substring that starts after the new line char:

```
update group_message 
set content = substr(content, instr(content, char(10)) + 1)
where 
  parent_id <> 0
  and 
  content like '%' || char(10) || '%'
```

If you want to keep that first new line char and delete only the text before it, then remove the `+1`.

Comment: Thank you, forpas. It worked for me and I learned something new. High five!

Comment: Everything you need to know about SQLite: https://www.sqlite.org/index.html and http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/ and of course this site.

Comment: Greatly appreciated!